# Do not match a word and then match a character thereafter

Tags: expression, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get a regular expression that matches a string that does not contain a certain word and contains a certain character after the word that was not matched. For instance, it should not match any word starting with 'break' followed by the ';' character, but should match any word that does not start with 'break' but ends with ';'. So in the following example:

```
break; // does not match
code // does not match
code; // matches
```

I've tried the following code, but it always matches:

```
/?!break;/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression below:

/^(?!(break)).+;$/gi

It catches everything which ends with ";" and avoid words which starts with "break"

I tested with these group of words:

break;
breakline
breakline;
line
**line;**
code
**code;**
something
**something;**

The bold words demonstrates which ones was selected by the regex.

Hope it helps